# What other PHP memory_limit restrictions could there be besides php.ini?

Tags: 7, drush

I have been facing some weird memory limit issues on a managed dedicated server and spent alot of time trying to fix this other with the server admin. phpinfo() is showing the correct overridden memory_limit values.
Everything is cool, except when I use drush to do `drush en module` or Views Bulk Operation execution. If anyone has experienced this before, I will really appreciate if you can share with us the steps needed to fix this.

In my php.ini :`memory_limit = 256M ;`

In sites/default/settings.php: `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');`

The WSOD message after executing a Views Bulkd Operations on ONE entry:
`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 131334144) (tried to allocate 5 bytes) in /public_html/includes/cache.inc on line 401
Memory used at: devel_boot()=5.02 MB, devel_shutdown()=82.06 MB, PHP peak=82.25 MB.`

In SSH, using drush cli. After running `drush en languageassign`:
`The following extensions will be enabled: languageassign
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y`

`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 76021760) (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /public_html/sites/all/modules/views/includes/base.inc on line 84`

`Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                      [error]`

`Error: Out of memory (allocated 76021760) (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in
/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/includes/base.inc, line 84`

Comment: are you sure init_set is enabled and can modify your settings to that value?

Answer (score 2):

Try including "RLimitMem 128000000" in your .htacess file.

Answer (score 1):

Another place where the memory_limit could be set is your .htaccess file. For drush also check out the cli php.ini file, usually found at /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

To check if you correctly set memory_limit try this:

When running drupal from the webserver you can do this by going to admin/reports/status/php

For drush you can check your php settings by running this command: `php -i | grep memory_limit`

Comment: `# php -i | grep memory_limit`
`memory_limit => 256M => 256M`

Comment: In admin/reports/status/php, under `memory_limit` value is `256M`

Answer (score 0):

are you sure init_set is enabled and you can modify your settings to that value?

most shared/dedicated servers have a limit for some settings or ignore ini_set commands

Comment: Yea, I'm very sure it works, because the updated value is reflected in phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

Set memory limit in setting. php file using **ini_set('memory_limit' '256M')**. Also you need to check your php execution time because vbo need more time to executive the operation.